# Difference between ‘fachlich’ and ‘technisch’?

Tags: meaning, difference, meaning-in-context

I am an IT engineer in Germany. I came across the term *fachlich* in a ‘Grobkonzept’ for a large project.

I understand what *technisch* means but I have trouble understanding the difference between *fachlich* and *technisch.*

The closest I have come to understand *fachlich* is that it means *professional.* But for a huge project, when we talk about *fachliches Konzept,* I just can’t seem to understand it or make a distinction between *fachlich* and *technisch.* Or could we perhaps use the word *functional* to translate *fachlich?*

Comment: What *technisch* definitely does NOT cover, are accounting topics, like payment plan, which could be part of someting called *fachlich*. Somewhat recursively defined I would say, that *fachlich* is less technical than *technisch*.

Comment: At the same time it's wider in scope, though: _fachlich_ includes _technisch_, where appropriate, but not the other way round.

Comment: »Fachlich« is »according to the business«. That means: If you are developing software for a financial bank, then »fachlich« covers the needs of the bank. »Technisch« is »according to the technical implementation«. That means, which programming language you use, or which kind of database system. The bank-guys are not interested in those »technische Anforderungen« they have »fachliche Anforderungen«.

Comment: Could you provide a context in which the two words occur with regard to your sector?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm assuming you ask for "fachlich" with regards to IT design and requirements.

Traditional IT requirement analysis differentiates between *functional* and *non-functional* requirements.

This is expressed in German by

> fachliche Anforderungen

(this refers to requirements stated by the business [i.e. "Fach"] problem that your software wants to solve)

and

> technische Anforderungen

(this refers to requirements that stem from the technical IT environment)

In the same way, "Fachkonzept" refers to "functional requirement specification".

This deviation from English terminology has probably been taken because *non-functional* could be misunderstood as "nicht funktionierend" (i.e, "not working") in German.

Outside of IT, the usage of "fachlich" vs. "technisch" is a bit different and can be looked up in a standard dictionary.

Comment: I totally agree with your answer. More generalised one could say that 'fachlich' means the area of non-technical expertise - in IT it is the user. The model can be seen as "Fachkonzept" which provides the frame/conditions (knowledge, workflows, laws, rules, relations) whereas the implementation is the technical topic (specific servers, databases, roles and rights, restrictions, environment, platform etc.).

Comment: e.g. *fachlich*: "We want to keep track of something so we need a database for a variety of records with certain relations" *technisch*: "We need two synchronised Windows servers with MS SQL server, load balancing and traffic shaping ..."

Comment: Fachlich could be translated as 'in the domain of X', e.g. for audiological software, fachlich would relate to the parts (domain/expert knowledge) that come from the science of Audiology.

Comment: from which one test cases are driven, technisch requirement or fachlich requirement?

Comment: I think I do not understand this answer. It sounds as if functional/non-functional were somehow related to fachlich/technisch, even though these are two orthogonal concepts. In German: Es gibt fachliche funktionale, technische funktionale, fachliche nichtfunktionale und technische nichtfunktionale Anforderungen.

Comment: 'because non-functional could be misunderstood as "nicht funktionierend" (i.e, "not working") in German.' - I don't buy this. The English word "dysfunctional" is arguably *more* similar to "non-functional" than "nicht funktionierend" is to "nichtfunktional". Moreover, the word "nichtfunktional" is indeed used in this context in German.

Answer (score 5):

"Fachlich" refers to "subject matter" arising from *use*. This stems from the *demand* side of the equation.

"Technisch" refers to issues regarding the *technique* of production. This stems from the *supply* side of the equation.

Answer (score 3):

Even german IT specialists and their customers often do not know, what they excactly mean saying "fachlich" or "technisch". After being more than 20 years IT professional I can say, that the idea of using "fachlich vs. technisch" can be be applied in these situations:

1. to distinct aspects, which customer must and can be interested in (fachlich) from those, which are not that interesting for customer (technisch). Especially it is true, if speaking about "Konzepts", what you asked.
2. to express, that one is not responsible for a certain issue: "it's too 'technisch' for me" or "the problem is caused 'fachlich', not 'technisch' "
3. (rarely) as synonyms for "functional/non-functional" (requirenments)

'fachlich' however definitely doesn't mean 'professional', when speaking about requirements and concepts in IT.

It is really hard...